# Regex on zero or more character but not newline nor space in Python

Tags: python, regex

In Python, this is used

```
  date_time_reg_exp = re.compile(r'\d{4}[-/:._]\d{2}[-/:._]\d{2}[\S^\n*.$]')
```

on such data:

```
2019-07:27 22:04:38.635317100 -0700
2010/08/26
2019-07-27_2313hr_19sec
2019-07.27
```

however, I am getting

```
['2010/08/26\\', '2019-07-27_', '2019-07.27\\']
```

it is not picking up

```
2019-07:27 and 2019-07-27_2313hr_19sec
```

and there is extra `\\` at the end

How can this is corrected?

Thank you.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yvz24K/1

Comment: it's getting this instead: ['', '_2313hr_19sec']

it should be getting these:
     '2019-07:27',  
     '2010/08/26', 
     '2019-07-27_2313hr_19sec', 
     '2019-07.27'

Comment: date_time_reg_exp = re.compile(r'\d{4}[-\/:._]\d{2}[-\/:._]\d{2}([0-9-a-z_]+)?')

returns ['', '_2313hr_19sec']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character class `[\S^\n*.$]` matches 1 time any of the listed, that is why it does not math `2019-07:27`.

If you want to match `2019-07-27_2313hr_19sec` you could match the "date like" format and follow the match by matching 0+ times a non whitespace char `\S*`

```
\d{4}[-/:._]\d{2}[-/:._]?\d{2}\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QxZG2d/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xXQLpl)

For example

```
import re

date_time_reg_exp = re.compile(r'\d{4}[-/:._]\d{2}[-/:._]?\d{2}\S*')
s = ("2019-07:27 22:04:38.635317100 -0700\n"
    "2010/08/26\n"
    "2019-07-27_2313hr_19sec\n"
    "2019-07.27")
print(re.findall(date_time_reg_exp, s))
```

Result

> ['2019-07:27', '2010/08/26', '2019-07-27_2313hr_19sec', '2019-07.27']

Comment: Can you add how you are using `date_time_reg_exp` and what the string looks like?

Comment: how to omit '\\n'?

Comment: @MoirisaDikaiosýni Do you mean like this?https://regex101.com/r/QxZG2d/2/ See https://ideone.com/xXQLpl

Comment: date_time_reg_exp = re.compile(r'\d{4}[-/:._]\d{2}[-/:._]?\d{2}[^\s\n]*')
still gives ["2010/08/26\\n',", "2019-07-27_2313hr_19sec\\n',", "2019-07.27\\n',", '2019-07:27']

Comment: @MoirisaDikaiosýni Is it working for you? Did you see the demo link https://ideone.com/xXQLpl Does your string contain `\\n` instead of `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

The negation operator needs to be the first character to create a negated character class. To do what you attempted, maybe try `[^\s\n]`. There is no way for a character class to be partially negated (if you think about it, what would that mean?) - it's either an enumeration of allowed characters, or an enumeration of disallowed characters starting with the negation operator `^`.

Comment: Regular expressions match newlines just fine, either using `\n` or a negated character class that doesn't include `\n`. All `DOTALL` does is change the meaning of `.`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks, looks like Python's `re` differs from many others in this regard. Answer updated.